# Updating multiple records by hasMany relationship in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-6, laravel-7

I am trying to update multiple images in laravel, but i am unable to do this. When i stored image in my database then it's working fine but issue is with update.
Please let me know where i am mistaking. I have relation between image and blog table.

Here are my controller code...

```
public function update(Request $r, $blog)
{
    //dd($r->all());
    $type = 'blog_img';
    $chr = substr($r->title, 0, 1);

    if (!is_dir(public_path() . '/' . $type)) {
        $blogDir = public_path() . '/' . $type;
        mkdir($blogDir, 0777, true);
    }
    if (!is_dir(public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd"))) {
        $dateDir = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd");
        mkdir($dateDir, 0777, true);
    }

    if (!is_dir(public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/thumb')) {
        $thumbDir = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/thumb';
        mkdir($thumbDir, 0777, true);
    }

    if (!is_dir(public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/small')) {
        $smallDir = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/small';
        mkdir($smallDir, 0777, true);
    }

    if (!is_dir(public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/thumb' . '/' . $chr)) {
        $chrThumbDir = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/thumb' . '/' . $chr;
        mkdir($chrThumbDir, 0777, true);
    }

    if (!is_dir(public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/small' . '/' . $chr)) {
        $chrSmallDir = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/small' . '/' . $chr;
        mkdir($chrSmallDir, 0777, true);
    }

    $thumbDirPath = date("Ymd") . '/thumb/' . $chr;
    $smallDirPath = date("Ymd") . '/small/' . $chr;

    if ($r->hasFile('propertyImages')) {
        $blImage = [];
        //dd($r->blog_image);
        for ($v = 0; $v < count($r->blog_image); $v++) {
            $thums = $r->blog_image;
            $filnameSmall = 'small-' . uniqid($chr) . '-' . $v . '.' . $thums[$v]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img = Image::make($thums[$v]->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(300, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $smallPath = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/small' . '/' . $chr . '/' . $filnameSmall;
            if (file_exists($smallPath)) {
                $this->removeImage($smallPath);
            }
            $img->save($smallPath);

            $optimizerChain = OptimizerChainFactory::create();
            $optimizerChain->optimize($smallPath);

            $filnameLarge = 'thumb-' . uniqid($chr) . '-' . $v . '.' . $thums[$v]->getClientOriginalExtension();
            $img = Image::make($thums[$v]->getRealPath());
            $img->resize(1080, null, function ($constraint) {
                $constraint->aspectRatio();
            });
            $thumbPath = public_path() . '/' . $type . '/' . date("Ymd") . '/thumb' . '/' . $chr . '/' . $filnameLarge;

            if (file_exists($thumbPath)) {
                $this->removeImage($thumbPath);
            }
            $img->save($thumbPath);
            $optimizerChain->optimize($thumbPath);

            $blImage[$v]['small'] = $filnameSmall;
            $blImage[$v]['smallDirPath'] = $smallDirPath;
            $blImage[$v]['large'] = $filnameLarge;
            $blImage[$v]['thumbDirPath'] = $thumbDirPath;
        }
    }
    else {
        $blImage = NULL;
    }

    $images = $blImage;
    $blog = Blog::find($blog);
    $blog->name = $r->bl_name;
    $blog->slug = Str::slug($r->bl_slug);
    $blog->meta_title = $r->meta_title;
    $blog->meta_desc = $r->meta_desc;
    $blog->description = $r->overview;
    $blog->status = $r->status;
    $blog->blogTag()->delete();
    $tagNames = explode(',', $r->blogtags);
    foreach ($tagNames as $key => $value) {
        $blog->blogTag()->updateOrCreate([
            'tag_name' => $value,
            'tag_slug' => Str::slug($value, '-')
        ]);
    }
    if ($images != null) {
        for ($v = 0; $v <= array_key_last($images); $v++) {
            if (!empty($images[$v])) {
                $blog->blogImage()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $images[$v]['id']], [
                    'small_thumb' => $images[$v]['small'],
                    'small_thumb_url' => $images[$v]['smallDirPath'],
                    'large_thumb' => $images[$v]['large'],
                    'large_thumb_url' => $images[$v]['thumbDirPath'],
                ]);
            }
        }
    }

    $blog->save();
    return response()->json(['status' => 1], 200);
}
```

and here are my update image code in view file:

```
<div class="statbox widget box box-shadow">
                                <div class="widget-header">
                                    <div class="row">
                                        <div class="col-xl-12 col-md-12 col-sm-12 col-12">
                                            <h4>Upload Blog Image</h4>
                                        </div>      
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="widget-content widget-content-area">
                                    @forelse($blog->blogImage as $propImg)
                                    <div class="custom-file-container" data-upload-id="myFirstImage">
                                        <label>Upload (Single File) <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="custom-file-container__image-clear" title="Clear Image">x</a></label>
                                        <label class="custom-file-container__custom-file" >
                                            <input type="file" name="blog_image[]" class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-input" accept="image/*">
                                            <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10485760" />
                                            <span class="custom-file-container__custom-file__custom-file-control"></span>
                                        </label>
                                        <div class="custom-file-container__image-preview"><img src="{{ asset('blog_img/'.$propImg->small_thumb_url.'/'.$propImg->small_thumb)}}" style="max-height: 90px;">
                                        </div>
                                        @empty
                                        @endforelse
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
```

And here are the Bloh.php Model..

```
public function blogImage()
{
    return $this->hasMany(BlogImage::class);
}
```

and here are BlogImage.php Model..

```
public function blog()
{
    return $this->hasMany(Blog::class);
}
```

Comment: You have to change the relationship method

Comment: I cannot find in Your controller how You're getting `$images[$v]['id']`

Comment: `id` is `BlogImage` model primary id

Comment: @sainitor :) I know that it's primary id, but when You create images array You don't define `['id']` field to it

Comment: @sainitor I think better to do as in 2-nd way in my answer, below.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot find in Your controller how You're getting `$images[$v]['id']`, obviously nowhere since `$blImage` also don't have `id`

You've 2 ways:

1. loop through `$blog->blogImage()` and update according order:

replace:

`$blog = Blog::find($blog);`

to `$blog = Blog::with('blogImage')->find($blog);`

and change logic of relation manipulations:

```
if (is_array($images) AND !empty($images)) {
  $blogImages = $blog->blogImage;
  $count = count($blogImages);
  for ($v = 0; $v < count($images); $v++) {
    if ($v < $count-1 AND !empty($images[$v])) {
      $blogImages[$v]->update($images[$v]);
      continue;
    }
    $blog->blogImage->create($images[$v]);
  }
}
```

2. delete or keep previous images and do `createMany` as before:

replace this:

```
if ($images != null) {
    for ($v = 0; $v <= array_key_last($images); $v++) {
        if (!empty($images[$v])) {
            $blog->blogImage()->updateOrCreate(['id' => $images[$v]['id']], [
                'small_thumb' => $images[$v]['small'],
                'small_thumb_url' => $images[$v]['smallDirPath'],
                'large_thumb' => $images[$v]['large'],
                'large_thumb_url' => $images[$v]['thumbDirPath'],
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

to this:

```
if (is_array($images) AND !empty($images)) {
  // uncomment this if You want to delete previous images,
  // which is logically incorrect - since 
  // user is uploading image, not deleting it
  // $blog->blogImage()->delete(); 
  $blog->blogImage()->createMany($images);
}
```

[manual to createMany](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#the-create-method)